# Creating a dictionary using pandas, python, returns error: "return self._engine.get_loc(key)"

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

This is a sample of a data set

```
Umls                                    Snomed
C0027497/Nausea /Sign or Symptom    Nausea (finding)[FN/422587007] 
C0151786 / Muscle/Sign or Symptom   Muscle weakness [(finding) /FN/26544005]
C2127305 /bitter/ Sign or Symptom    ?
NA                                   NA
```

This is my code to create a dictionary of the data:

```
df_dic_1= df_dic_1[['UMLS', 'snomed']]

df_dic_1['umls'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df_dic_1['snomed'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

equiv_snomed=df_dic_1.set_index('umls')['snomed'].to_dict()
```

But it creates the following error:

```
"   return self._engine.get_loc(key)"
```

any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
df_dic_1= df_dic_1[['UMLS', 'snomed']]

df_dic_1['UMLS'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df_dic_1['snomed'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

equiv_snomed=df_dic_1.set_index('UMLS')['snomed'].to_dict()
```

because you have a key error

Answer (score 1):

There use 5 different column names for 2 columns:

`Umls` in sample, `UMLS` and `umls` in code.
`Snomed` in sample, `snomed` in code

You need check it by:

```
print (df.columns.tolist())
```

and use right one.

e.g. if correct names in sample:

```
f_dic_1= df_dic_1[['Umls', 'Snomed']]

df_dic_1['Umls'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df_dic_1['Snomed'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

equiv_snomed=df_dic_1.set_index('Umls')['Snomed'].to_dict()
```